# Ошибка при декодировании JSON

Tags: json, ios, swift, swift4

У меня есть функция

```
 func fetchPhotoRequest()  {


    let string = "https://tilqural.kz/api/v1/education/courses"
    let url = NSURL(string: string)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.setValue("f31812717dfd0b71a5fc09ab18b3ad6f", forHTTPHeaderField: "hash")
    request.setValue("application/x.LMS.v1+json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue("4", forHTTPHeaderField: "user")
    request.setValue("ru", forHTTPHeaderField: "language")
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let session = URLSession.shared

    guard let curl = URL(string: string) else { return }
    let mData = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let res = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: curl) { [unowned self] (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                                let data_new = try decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: data)


                                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                                    self.tableview.reloadData()
                                    print(data_new.message)
                                }

                            } catch {
                                print("Error is : \n\(error)")
                            }
            }.resume()


            print("res: \(String(describing: res))")
            print("Response: \(String(describing: response))")
        }else{
            print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
        }
    }
    mData.resume()
}
```

Вот декод json

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
let statusCode: Int
let message: String
let content: [Content]
  }

struct Content: Codable {
let id: Int
let slug, title: String
let canAccess, passed: Int
let sections: [Content]?
let lessons: [Lesson]?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id, slug, title
    case canAccess = "can_access"
    case passed, sections, lessons
}
}

struct Lesson: Codable {
let id, position: Int
let title, slug: String
let image: String
let canAccess, passed: Int

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id, position, title, slug, image
    case canAccess = "can_access"
    case passed
}}
```

Вот сам json

```
{
"statusCode": 200,
"message": "Список курсов",
"content": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "slug": "kurs-a1",
        "title": "Курс А1",
        "can_access": 1,
        "passed": 1,
        "sections": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "slug": "razdel-1",
                "title": "Раздел 1",
                "can_access": 1,
                "passed": 0,
                "lessons": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "position": 1,
                        "title": "Сәлемдесу",
                        "slug": "salemdesu",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 1,
                        "passed": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "position": 2,
                        "title": "Танысу",
                        "slug": "tanysu",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 1,
                        "passed": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "slug": "razdel-2",
                "title": "Раздел 2",
                "can_access": 0,
                "passed": 0,
                "lessons": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "position": 3,
                        "title": "Бұл – менің отбасым",
                        "slug": "bul-menin-otbasym",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "position": 4,
                        "title": "Жасы нешеде?",
                        "slug": "zhasy-neshede",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "slug": "razdel-3",
                "title": "Раздел 3",
                "can_access": 0,
                "passed": 0,
                "lessons": [
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "position": 5,
                        "title": "Туған күн",
                        "slug": "tugan-kun",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 9,
                        "position": 6,
                        "title": "Құттықтау",
                        "slug": "kuttyktau",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "slug": "razdel-4",
                "title": "Раздел 4",
                "can_access": 0,
                "passed": 0,
                "lessons": [
                    {
                        "id": 10,
                        "position": 7,
                        "title": "Адам келбеті",
                        "slug": "adam-kelbeti",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 12,
                        "position": 8,
                        "title": "Адамның мінез-құлқы",
                        "slug": "adamnyn-minez-kulky",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "slug": "razdel-5",
                "title": "Раздел 5",
                "can_access": 0,
                "passed": 0,
                "lessons": [
                    {
                        "id": 13,
                        "position": 9,
                        "title": "Менің мамандығым",
                        "slug": "menin-mamandygym",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 15,
                        "position": 10,
                        "title": "Кім болып жұмыс істейді?",
                        "slug": "kim-bolyp-zhumys-istejdi",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "slug": "razdel-6",
                "title": "Раздел 6",
                "can_access": 0,
                "passed": 0,
                "lessons": [
                    {
                        "id": 16,
                        "position": 11,
                        "title": "Жұмыс орны",
                        "slug": "zhumys-orny",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 17,
                        "position": 12,
                        "title": "Жұмыс күні",
                        "slug": "zhumys-kuni",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "slug": "razdel-7",
                "title": "Раздел 7",
                "can_access": 0,
                "passed": 0,
                "lessons": [
                    {
                        "id": 19,
                        "position": 13,
                        "title": "Тесты ЦОР-а",
                        "slug": "testy",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 20,
                        "position": 14,
                        "title": "Тесты",
                        "slug": "testy",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "slug": "razdel-8",
                "title": "Раздел 8",
                "can_access": 0,
                "passed": 0,
                "lessons": [
                    {
                        "id": 22,
                        "position": 15,
                        "title": "Тесты",
                        "slug": "testy",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 23,
                        "position": 16,
                        "title": "Тесты",
                        "slug": "testy",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "slug": "razdel-9",
                "title": "Раздел 9",
                "can_access": 0,
                "passed": 0,
                "lessons": [
                    {
                        "id": 25,
                        "position": 17,
                        "title": "Тесты",
                        "slug": "testy",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 27,
                        "position": 18,
                        "title": "Тесты",
                        "slug": "testy",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "slug": "razdel-10",
                "title": "Раздел 10",
                "can_access": 0,
                "passed": 0,
                "lessons": [
                    {
                        "id": 28,
                        "position": 19,
                        "title": "Тесты",
                        "slug": "testy",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 29,
                        "position": 20,
                        "title": "Тесты",
                        "slug": "testy",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "slug": "razdel-11",
                "title": "Раздел 11",
                "can_access": 0,
                "passed": 0,
                "lessons": [
                    {
                        "id": 32,
                        "position": 21,
                        "title": "Тесты",
                        "slug": "testy",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 33,
                        "position": 22,
                        "title": "Тесты",
                        "slug": "testy",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "slug": "razdel-12",
                "title": "Раздел 12",
                "can_access": 0,
                "passed": 0,
                "lessons": [
                    {
                        "id": 34,
                        "position": 23,
                        "title": "Тесты",
                        "slug": "testy",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 35,
                        "position": 24,
                        "title": "Тесты",
                        "slug": "testy",
                        "image": "https://tilqural.kz/assets/img/default-lesson-icon.png",
                        "can_access": 0,
                        "passed": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Я хочу его вывести в collection view
Но у меня не получается, в консоле пишет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот так выглядит GET запрос
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Что я сделал неправильно? 
Задекодил или написал функцию

Answer (score 0):

Так попробуйте, вообще не стоит надеяться на то что данные могут 100% прети, поэтому есть смысл делать опционалами:

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let statusCode: Int
    let message: String
    let content: [Content]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case statusCode
        case message
        case content
    }
}
```

UPD:
Ошибка у вас в декодировании.

Answer (score 0):

```
// To parse the JSON, add this file to your project and do:
//
//   let welcome = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: jsonData)

import Foundation

struct Welcome: Codable {
    let statusCode: Int?
    let message: String?
    let content: [Content]?
}

struct Content: Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let slug, title: String?
    let canAccess, passed: Int?
    let sections: [Content]?
    let lessons: [Lesson]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, slug, title
        case canAccess = "can_access"
        case passed, sections, lessons
    }
}

struct Lesson: Codable {
    let id, position: Int?
    let title, slug: String?
    let image: String?
    let canAccess, passed: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, position, title, slug, image
        case canAccess = "can_access"
        case passed
    }
}
```

Попробуй использовать это